# Webpack loader to emit a file at the end of compilation

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to write a loader which at then of the compilation will emit a file with contents gathered from all the passes.

Currently, I do:

```
const cache = [];

module.exports = function loader(content) {
  const deps = [];
  const context = this;
  const options = loaderUtils.getOptions(this) || {};

  // process the module

  // after each pass store the file in the cache
  cache.push(someIdentifier)

  // at the end, emit the contents of the cache to a file 
  // effectively replacing its previous contents
  this.emitFile('file.json', JSON.stringify(cache))

  // ...
```

The above is working fine up until version 4.40 but after it throws an error:

`Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename ...`

So, obviously, the Webpack devs don't want me to do it like this. Is there a way to override it or a better solution?